# Multiple result sets excluding column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a collection of entries in a table, table is joined with another table and together I need to return a resultset excluding entries by a particular date value.

Table 1

[image: lookup table]

I need to return a collection of entries based on a query and find the value, along with a collection of other items where the date as per the screenshot is <= GETDATE()

Results should be

[image: results]

As you can see, the resultset returns all three of the General Worker items but should only return where the date time is <= GetDate().

I have tried various approaches, from the (SELECT .. (PARTITION)) approach to sub-value table results and none of them return the resultset I need.

I need all other rows intact with only the General Worker where date <= GETDATE() and I'm stuck.

**UPDATE**

My T-SQL statement before modifications:

```
SELECT
    T0.nContractID,
    T1.sJobCatNo,
    T1.nJobCatID,
    T1.sJobCatDesc,
    T1.nDeleted,
    T1.nAdminLocked,
    T1.nClientDefault,
    T1.nRateNT,
    CASE
        WHEN (T0.sDistributionCode IN ('Nails', 'Board'))
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS 'ShowRate'
FROM
    [dbo].[Contract] AS T0
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[JobCategoryRates] AS T1 ON T1.nContractID = T0.nContractID
WHERE
    T1.nContractID = 200198
    AND T1.nDeleted = 0
ORDER BY
    T1.sJobCatDesc
```

**UPDATE 2**

I need the results to look like this:

[image]

**UPDATE 3**

Maybe this might help?

Table 1, for nContractID returns 19 results (3 of which are the same), the only distinct value is the dEndDate column should should be <= GETDATE(). I need to extract all values where dEndDate is null and dEndDate <= GETDATE(). Everything I've tried thus far brings back only one result, but logic in my head says I should have 17 results, if the dEndDate items >= GETDATE() is removed?

Comment: Have you tried adding AND T1.[Date] <= GETDATE() to your WHERE clause?

Comment: @SteveFord yes, it returns a single result, the other columns disappear.

Comment: if you need to see the rows with nulls then you could try AND (T1.[Date] <=GetDate() OR T1.[Date] IS NULL)

Answer (score 2):

Need to clean up the query and your thought process

If you want to debug dEndDate then include it in the output

All values where dEndDate is null and dEndDate <= GETDATE() is always false.
A value cannot be null and have a value.

In the default configuration a comparison to null is always false.
null <=  1/1/2000 is false
null >=  1/1/2000 is false
null = null is false

If you want null OR dEndDate <= GETDATE() then:

```
where dEndDate is null or dEndDate <= GETDATE()
```

Why would you expect this not to return one row?

```
dEndDate <= GETDATE()
```